# Is that possible for Windows to play format playlist.m3u8 which made fully support on iOS or Mac?

Tags: windows, mac, playlists, ios

There are live TV and radio channels which the file format is `playlist.m3u8` and this file can be played on iOS as well as Mac OS X.

I wonder if there is any workaround or way to make it play on Windows OS or any browser plugin so that I can play them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty much any player that supports .m3u playlists should be able to handle the .m3u8 playlists,  there just may be some character display problems (since .m3u8 is a Unicode version of .m3u to support extended character sets).

Available [here](http://extension.nirsoft.net/m3u8) is a list of players that support the .m3u8 file type specifically.

[WinAmp](http://www.winamp.com/) is my personal favorite for media playing on Windows.

Comment: Thanks but what if that playlist.m3u8 created to work on the iOS or Mac is that going to make any difference? since I tried on VLC and it doesn't work

Comment: Depends on the file path. Unix systems use a / for folders, Macs use / or : depending on the situation, and Windows uses a \. You may need to edit the file manually to change those

Comment: @Luke and what if I don't own the file?

Comment: Then it's gonna be hard to use it :p Use wget (or another program) to download the raw playlist file, then open in Notepad or TextEdit or whatever ASCII app you have

Answer (score 2):

m3u8 playlists are used to implement HTTP Live Streaming (HLS) which is a way of streaming live video (H.264 and AAC) over HTTP

HTTP Live Streaming is supported by Mac OS X and iOS, and Android Ice Cream Sandwhich, but I don't know of any Windows based players.

There is an SDK you can get to allow the writing of Windows 8 and Windows Phone 8 applications which support HLS

[3ivx HLS Client SDK for Windows 8 and Windows Phone 8](http://www.3ivx.com/technology/windows/metro/http_live_streaming.html)